# d3 linechart transition with missing data

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, linechart

On our website we draw animated linecharts using d3, created using the following example:
http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326

Sometimes it happens for some points there's no data, so we updated the chart using the defined method (like this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/0533f44f2cfabecc5e3a)

The problem we now have is that when using the code for transition:

```
                linePath
                .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
                .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
                .transition()
                .duration(2000)
                .ease(d3.easeLinear)
                .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

each line of the path is drawn at the same time, as you can see here:
https://jsfiddle.net/applepie89/9kknu8du/

Is there a way/solution to draw it the way it draws the line without missing data? So each "part" follows up the the previous "part"

Comment: So you want to keep the gaps, *and* the animation to happen for each segment one at a time (as if the line was continuous)? So, removing the gaps is not a solution, right?

Comment: yes, correctly. If we only use one line we could indeed remove the gap, but if we use multiple lines (wich we sometimes do) the gap needs to be there to show the missing data, because for the other line there will be data

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure. I was initially surprised about the behavior, because you have a single `path` element, but it seems that's the CSS way... Here `d3` creates the `path` and gives it a `stroke-dashoffset` attribute that is then progressively modified from `totalLength` to `0`. Not explaining to you your own code, just sharing my understanding... correct or incorrect, maybe a CSS expert will see this, jump in, correct me and offer you a solution...

Comment: On subject of "Animating SVG paths with discontinuous parts", bad news, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39896469/6730571), it does not seem possible with a single `path`.

Comment: thnx for the reaction.. because you said it seems not possible with a single path, I created a work-around with multiple paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments of Hugues Moreau it does not seem possible to achieve the result with a single path, so I've created a work-around for myself.

At the start there's an array with data, with the null-values in it.
I create a new array and add sub-arrays to this array.

```
var newObjectArray = [];
var duration = 2000;
var duration_per_point = duration / d.values.length;
var delay = 0;
var start = 0;
for (var j = 0; j < d.values.length; j++)
{
   if (isNaN(d.values[j].y))
   {
       var tempArray = d.values.slice(start, j);
       newObjectArray.push(tempArray );
       start = j;
    }
 }
 newObjectArray.push(d.values.slice(start, j));
```

for each array in the newObjectArray I now draw a path, and add delay to the transition.

```
linePath
    .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
    .transition()
    .duration(duration_per_point*newObjectArray[k].length)
    .delay(delay)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

delay += duration_per_point * newObjectArray[k].length;
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9kknu8du/4/

Comment: Nice of you to share a complete solution.